# Did Molly Weasley Use Deletrius on Bellatrix Lestrange?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

I believe she did in the movie, but I'm not sure about in the book.

Comment: What makes you think she did in the films?

Comment: @Bellatrix Bella!!!! you're back!! ;)

Comment: @Shreedhar Yes I am, it’s so good to be alive!!! ;)

Answer (score 6):

The only example of Deletrius being cast that we see is when Amos Diggory uses it to make the ghost of a spell created by Prior Incantato disappear:

> '*Prior Incantato!*' roared Mr Diggory.
>
> Harry heard Hermione gasp, horrified, as a gigantic serpent-tongued skull erupted from the point where the two wands met, but it was a mere shadow of the green skull high above them, it looked as though it was made of thick grey smoke: the ghost of a spell.
>
> '*Deletrius!*' Mr Diggory shouted, and the smoky skull vanished in a wisp of smoke.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* - pp.121-2 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 9, *The Dark Mark*

There is no canon indication that this is a generally destructive spell, or suitable for use in combat, or anything other than Prior Incantato's "stop button".

The example of Deletrius being used in *The Goblet of Fire* bears no resemblance to Bellatrix's death in the book.

> Molly's curse soared beneath Bellatrix's outstretched arm and hit her squarely in the chest, directly over her heart.
>
> Bellatrix's gloating smile froze, her eyes seemed to bulge: for the tiniest space of time she knew what had happened, and then she toppled, and the watching crowd roared, and Voldemort screamed.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.590 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 36, *The Flaw in the Plan*